# Unix command parameter and option order

Tags: unix, command, pipe

I am new to Unix. 
I am wondering if the order of the options and parameters passed to a specific command matter?
For instance:

```
$grep -i -P 'wonderful' filename
$grep filename -i 'wonderful' -P
```

Do they mean exactly the same thing?

And if they don't mean the same thing, in unix pipe, since the result of the first command is going to be passed to the second command as input, and in which position the output is going to be placed in the second command's input parameters?
for example:

```
$echo "This is a wonderful day"|grep -P -i 'Wonderful'
```

is this equivalent to:

```
$grep -P -i 'Wonderful' $(echo "This is a wonderful day")
```

or in some other order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it doesn't matter, but there is some command for which order is important. No general rule. Read the manual carefully...